# Twitter Bootstrap - fixed background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have managed to add a custom background to my site. I change the body in the bootstrap.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-image: url("../images/norn-race.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

My problem is that it is not responsive, If i zoom in the background gets bigger and if I zoom out the background gets smaller, but it should be always be the same size on different resolutions.

Where is my mistake?

I should also add the background is only visible on the left and right. At the moment I am just using a big background to cover everything, which is unnecessary, because 80% is hidden by my content.

What is the correct approach to show images on the left and right?

Comment: Zoom and resolution are not the same thing. You should resize your window instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

responsive image work when your image is in the content, aka as a `<img src="" alt="">`, not when set as background-image

Answer (score 0):

check background-size property for responsive-design background size